# How to set Drop Down value based on another drop down using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an html table with n table record.

```
<tr>@Html.DropDown("Name1", SelectList)<tr>
<tr>@Html.DropDown("Name2", SelectList)<tr>
<tr>@Html.DropDown("Name3", SelectList)<tr>
<tr>@Html.DropDown("Name4", SelectList)<tr>
 ..
 ..
```

I am in the need of jquery solution , so that when I change Items in #Name (first), same should be reflected in other  Drop down. SelectList is common for all dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<select id="first">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
<select id="second"  class="group_member">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
<select id="third" class="group_member">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
```

Use this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#first").change(function(){
        $("#second").val($(this).val());
        $("#third").val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

OR

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#first").change(function(){
            $(".group_member").val($(this).val()); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: // $(".group_member").val($(this).val());    gave me a hint to my problem

Comment: I have added this line so that you don't have to mention id's of each div (#second, #third)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this works,

```
<select name="first" id="first">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<select name="second" id="second">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#first',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $('#second').val($this.val());
    });
});
</script>
```